# In wcf IMetaDataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'HelloService'

Tags: wcf, hosting

Error showing :The contract name 'IMetaDataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'HelloService'.

My App.config is given below. Why occuring this please guide me.

```
<services>
  <service name="HelloService.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
    <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetaDataExchange"></endpoint>
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Description.IMetadataExchange" />-->
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://10.135.32.65:8080/"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the casing you wrote the tag (IMetadataExchange):

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetaDataExchange"></endpoint>
```

Must be:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
```

Hope it helps